# How to add link breadcrumb to the site

Tags: breadcrumb

I have got a site on a site, and on the site. How Could I do a breadcrumb on a site which on a site and which on a site. Sharepoint 2013.

Answer (score 1):

The work around is to use `SiteMapPath` to build the bread-crumb back in the master page but it doesn't respect security trimming, means users gonna see everything even if they don't have the access to.

Comment: But how implement SiteMapPath ? Have You. Got a guide how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Wouter Laureys has an article: http://blog.amtopm.be/2013/01/04/sp2013-adding-breadcrumbs/

What you need is to add to master page

```
<!--MS:<asp:sitemappath runat="server" sitemapproviders="SPSiteMapProvider,SPXmlContentMapProvider" rendercurrentnodeaslink="false" hideinteriorrootnodes="true">-->
<!--ME:</asp:sitemappath>-->
```

Or look up other options in his article.